# Capture regex group in sh script

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script, the default interpreter is `/bin/sh`.

My script looks like this:

```
echo "Starting watchdog"
INFO=$(cat /tmp/info)
RE="s\=([0-9]+)"
if [[$INFO =~ $RE]]; then
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

I get the error like this `test.sh: line 6: [[do: not found`

I assume `${BASH_REMATCH[1]};` is incorrect, but what variable do I use to capture regex if i use `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: Regex support is not a feature that exists at all in `sh`. Unless you're going to use tools that aren't part of the shell itself (awk, etc), the answer is "you can't". Why would bash have added extended syntax for the feature if it already existed in `sh`?

Comment: BTW, even in bash, your code above is invalid -- you can't leave out the spaces. `[[ $info =~ $re ]]`, not `[[$info =~ $re]]`. (And note the use of lower-case variable names -- all-caps names can conflict with variables meaningful to the shell itself; see POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, reserving names with at least one lower-case character for application use and guaranteeing that they won't change the behavior of POSIX-defined tools).

Comment: ...that said, what are you actually trying to match/extract, and from what kind of larger string? The tools `sh` *does* have (not regexes with match groups, but some simple fnmatch-style globbing capabilities) may suffice for the actual use case at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you're using bash conditions incorrectly. The `[[` command needs spaces before and after it. It's not just a language construct, it's an actual *command*, which takes the parts of your condition as options. That said, it's a command that exists solely as a built-in to bash, it's not something you can use in a normal POSIX shell script.

The canonical POSIX method for handling regex conditions with variables in shell scripts is [`expr(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html). That said, if you're parsing a file, `grep` is a classic.

Avoiding bashisms, you might do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

RE="s\=([0-9]+)"

if egrep "$RE" /tmp/info >/dev/null; then
  printf 'Found it!\n'
fi
```

Or if you really want to do this using your `$INFO` variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

INFO="$(cat /tmp/info)"
RE='.*s=[0-9][0-9]*'

if expr "$INFO" : "$RE" >/dev/null; then
  printf 'Found it!\n'
fi
```

Note the adjusted RE, since `expr` automatically anchors to the start of your input, and only uses BRE rather than ERE.

Now... If you need to extract the *value* that you appear to be fetching within the brackets, you have a little more parsing to do.

```
#!/bin/sh

RE="s=([0-9]+)"

output="$(egrep -o "$RE" /tmp/info | head 1)"  #  fetch the output, if any
output="${output#s=}"                          #  strip off the "s=" at the beginning

if [ -n "$output" ]; then                      #  if we found anything...
  printf 'Found it: %s!\n' "$output"           #  print it!
fi
```

Note the use of `egrep` to parse ERE rather than the default BRE. Adjust as required for your environment. (I understand that some Linuces have taken to recommending against `egrep` in favour of `grep -E`.)

Also note that if you're trying to capture something from input data that looks more like `abc=foo&jobs=5&s=important+data`, your results may not be what you expect, using a RE like the ones above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/bin/sh` equivalent to this feature at all.

Consider using `awk`:

```
awk -F= '/s=[[:digit:]]+$/ { print $2; exit(0); }' </tmp/info
```

Answer (score 0):

The *POSIX* shell's built-in `case` statement has [*pattern matching*](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch35_11.htm).  *Pattern matching* is less powerful than *regex*, but it can match something simple like `RE="s\=([0-9]+)"`.

Example, match if there's a number in the `$n` variable:

```
n=number1 m= ; \
case "$n" in *[0-9]*) ;; *) m="not " ;; esac; printf 'number %sfound\n' "$m"
```

Output:

```
number found
```

With no number:

```
n=number m= ; \
case "$n" in *[0-9]*) ;; *) m="not " ;; esac ; printf 'number %sfound\n' "$m"
```

Output:

```
number not found
```

So there's that, and within certain limits a pattern can even be put in a variable:

```
n=number1 m= p='[0-9]'; \
case "$n" in *$p*) ;; *) m="not " ;; esac ; printf 'number %sfound\n' "$m"
```

Output:

```
number found
```